# Logging to Stackdriver using Logback's Console JSON Appender

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logback, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to get **Stackdriver** to pick up my logs correctly, using the logging agent on a **Compute Engine** VM and the **Console JSON** appender of **Logback**.

In logback, I have the following config:

```xml
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/logging/logback-json-appender.xml"/>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_JSON"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

On the Compute VM, I've installed the logging agent, with the structured config:

```sh
curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/install-logging-agent.sh
sudo bash install-logging-agent.sh --structured
```

The logs from the app are JSON, and end up in `syslog` along the lines of:

```
Sep 11 08:21:08 backend-1 env[2440]: {"timestampSeconds":1568190068,"timestampNanos":703000000,"severity":"DEBUG","thread":"main","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig","message":"idleTimeout.....................600000","context":"default"}
```

The issue is that Stackdriver picks them up as text and they end up in a bad state in the Stackdriver Logs viewer:

```
{
 insertId:  "y5oc1500...f1j4fh"  
 jsonPayload: {
  host:  "backend-1"   
  ident:  "env"   
  message:  "{"timestampSeconds":1568190911,"timestampNanos":802000000,"severity":"DEBUG","thread":"HikariPool-1 connection closer","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase","message":"HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@64c28b76: (connection has passed idleTimeout)","context":"default"}"   
  pid:  "2440"   
 }
 labels: {…}  
 logName:  "projects/g...o/logs/syslog"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-09-11T08:35:17.538019705Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 timestamp:  "2019-09-11T08:35:11Z"  
}
```

It seems that instead of picking up the JSON in the message as the log entry, it just treats it as a raw text. What am I missing?